# Reading the contents of the file to an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, csv

How to read the Contents of the CSV file to an array in the objective c..
I Have a CSV file where i need to read the contents of it in a array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - Here, I expect a file `array.out` in documents directory. This file I read it into an `NSArray` and iterate through it...

```
// Get path to documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if([paths count] > 0)
{
  // Path to save array data
  NSString  *arrayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"array.out"];

  // Read both back in new collections
  NSArray *arrayFromFile = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:arrayPath];

  for (NSString *element in arrayFromFile) 
    NSLog(@"Beer: %@", element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` provides some high level support for this.

to read the file, use something like this:

```
NSString * file = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path
    encoding:encoding error:&error];
```

then to divide the string, use something like:

`NSArray * values = [file componentsSeparatedByString:separator];`

or

`NSArray * values = [file componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separatorSet];`